# Bulletproofs with ranges not in power of two

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I am new to [bulletproofs](https://crypto.stanford.edu/bulletproofs/). From what I understand, if I was to do a range proof using bulletproofs, both the start and end number have to be a power of 2.

is there any algorithm/approach which can be used to expand this to numbers that are not powers of 2?

Example: find if a number is in the range 18 to 65?

Comment: You can use an AND statement to do this. Give your number x, prove that (x-18) > 0 AND (65-x) > 0 . Bulletproofs can be used with arithmetic circuits, so you could build the statement above

Comment: yes, that's it thanks, how do i accept your answer? don't see an option

Comment: I added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an AND statement to do this.

To prove that x is between `a` and `b` , you can prove that (x-a) > 0 AND (b-x) > 0